# Vivado HLS_C code

Tags: http-live-streaming, vivado

I am trying to write and execute the C code program for data communication. Please can anyone help me in writing the Program for HLS?

Tried in normal C code program like using `PRINTF` and `SCANF` statements but it's showing a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

When you use HLS you are going to "translate" your C code in HLD (VHDL or Verilog for example). Because of this, there are some restrictions: you cannot use "printf", "scanf", malloc and so on. For instance: how can you implement a printf in HLD upon an FPGA?
I recommend reading this [tutorial](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_2/ug871-vivado-high-level-synthesis-tutorial.pdf) and this [user guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_1/ug902-vivado-high-level-synthesis.pdf).

However, you can use "printf" **ONLY** in HLS simulation: at the end, you will not synthesize it. [Here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/How-to-print-the-info-of-quot-printf-quot-in-Vivado-HLS/td-p/662981) you can find the link to the discussion about this on Xilinx's forum.

You can update your question and add some more details in order to understand where the errors occur.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: If it was helpful, You can accept the answer clicking on the "tic" that will become green (just on the right side close to the answer).

Comment: Hi, please provide me simple C coding example for vivado HLS

Comment: Yes, ask another question please with some details more: what should the C code do? Just post your first attempt and we will correct it and reply with the right code

Comment: int bin_verify(char[]);
int main()
{
char bin1[33],bin2[33],result[33];
int len1, lens2,check;
 printf("binary number 1:");
scanf ("%s", bin1);
printf("binary number 2:");
fscanf ("%s", bin2);
check=bin_verify(bin1);
if(check)
{
 printf("Invalid binary number%s.\n", bin1);
 exit(0);
}
check =bin_verify(bin2);
if(check)
{
 printf("Invalid binary number%s.\n", bin2);
 exit(0);
}
frintf("output binary %s.\n", bin1);

printf("output binary %s.\n", bin2);
return 0;
}

Comment: Codes Not arranging in correct format. I dont know y..Sorry for posting like this.